# No se si mi programa comprime a .ZIP

Tags: python, tkinter, zip

estoy haciendo un programa que comprime archivos a .ZIP. Pero, al convertirlos el archivo aparece de una manera extraña(El archivo zip aparece con una ruta en lugar de salir como lo haría con WinRAR).
Les dejo unas capturas de mi código así como del problema que tengo y como debería funcionar(WinRAR).
Gracias.[image: Código][image: Comprimido con WinRAR][image: Comprimido con mi programa]

Este es el código:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import zipfile

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

print(filename)
Ruta = filename

archivoZIP = zipfile.ZipFile('Tu Archivo ZIP.zip','w')
archivoZIP.write((Ruta),compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
archivoZIP.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu programa comprime a zip, no hay problema con eso, la ruta es un pequeño malentendido común con ZipFile, [veamos la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write), traducción libre:

> ```
> ZipFile.write (filename, arcname = None, compress_type = None, compresslevel = None)
> ```
>
> Escribe el archivo llamado `filename` en el archivo, dándole el
>   nombre de arcname (**por defecto, será el mismo que el de
>   `filename`**, pero sin la letra de unidad y con los separadores de
>   ruta principales eliminados).

Como le pasas solo `filename`, primer argumento posicional, toma dicha ruta como nombre del archivo, con las variaciones comentadas con respecto a letra de unidad y demás. Es más, te genera en el .zip la estructura de archivos completa de la rusta hasta el archivo.

La solución es hacer uso de `arcname` y pasar el nombre que queremos que tenga el archivo, generalmente el nombre del archivo original (basename):

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import zipfile


Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
path = Path(filename)

archivoZIP = zipfile.ZipFile('Tu Archivo ZIP.zip','w')
archivoZIP.write(path, arcname=path.name, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
archivoZIP.close()
```